# lvalue to rvalue conversion

Tags: c++, стандарт

Что такое *lvalue to rvalue conversion*? В этой [статье](https://rsdn.org/article/cpp/lvalue.xml) непонятно следующее:

> Очевидно, что если мы будем использовать любое из приведенных ранее
>   lvalue-выражений в контексте, требующем значения объекта (например, в
>   правой части операции присваивания), использование компилятором
>   адресов будет ошибкой. Т.е., хотя выражение i является lvalue ("адрес
>   и значение"), компилятор должен использовать соответствующее rvalue
>   ("значение"). В терминах стандарта C++ это называется преобразованием
>   lvalue к rvalue (lvalue-to-rvalue conversion).

Что этим хотел сказать автор?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну примерно...

Смотрите, переменная как таковая является lvalue -

```
int i;
i = 4;
```

Здесь de facto используется *адрес* переменной `i` - *куда* записать значение 4.

```
int i, j;
i = 4;
j = i;
```

А что теперь? Теперь в первом присваивании `i` выступает как lvalue - т.е. используется как указание на место в памяти, а во втором - уже как rvalue - не как указание на место в памяти, а как *значение*, в этом месте хранящееся.

Т.е. из lvalue получено rvalue. Т.е. компилятор преобразовал lvalue в rvalue - выполнил *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion*.

Так более-менее понятно или нужно еще поговорить?..

Comment: почему компилятор преобразовал lvalue в rvalue, к чему такое преобразование? что бы прочитать значение нужно обязательно преобразовывать lvalue в rvalue?

Comment: как я понял, компилятор может но не обязан приводить lvalue в rvalue?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Я бы сказал, что для обычного программиста эти тонкости излишни и запутывающи. Так сказать, не берите дурное в голову и тяжелое в руки :) А так... Даже не знаю, что, кроме стандарта, посоветовать... Ну, вот у Вандевурда-Джосаттиса-Грегора в "Шаблонах С++" было более-менее адекватное описание всех этих ?-value. У Майерса в "Эффективном С++", кажется.

Comment: Компилятор вынужден его делать, но вам, как программисту, до этого в 99.99% случаев нет никакого дела...

Comment: понятно, спасибо, тонкости излишни, но я сторонник высказывания "Зри в корень"

Comment: Компилятор вынужден его делать в целях оптимизации как я понимаю?

Comment: Нет, просто *чтение значения по некоторому адресу (из переменной)* и **есть** *преобразование lvalue (адреса) в rvalue (значение)*.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81156/discussion-between-stanislav-petrov-and-harry).

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто и нужно внимательно прочитать выше в статье, что написано.

rvalue - это только значение (оно не имеет адреса)
lvalue - это нечто, что обладает и значением и адресов.

В случае примера

`int j; int i;
j = i;`

обе переменные i и j могут быть lvalue (т.е. могут находится слева от оператора присваивания), но в примере от i нам нужно только значение, поэтому lvalue преобразуется в rvalue.

Comment: Объяснение с адресом больше запутывает. Мы же можем взять адрес `i`, тем не менее, это выражение является prvalue. Зря этот пример приводят.

Comment: @gecube зачем преобразовывать lvalue в rvalue, почему нельзя просто прочитать значение?