# Что такое lvalues, rvalues и т.д.?

Tags: c++, c++17

Что такое lvalues, rvalues, xvalues и т.п. в `C++`? Насколько я понимаю, многое изменилось с `C++17` и толкового объяснения нигде не найти.

Comment: По-моему уже было

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864422/lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion

Comment: Прям вообще нигде не найти?